# Multiple inference lines of single inference rule

Tags: semantics

I looked at both the **semantic** and **mathpartir** package, is is possible to insert multiple inference lines in single inference rules? Or are there better ways to do this?

[image]

The mathpartir package has a little example but it does not work very well and I can't find any better solutions.

```
\documentclass[12pt, notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage{mathpartir}

\begin{document}

\section{Judgement}

$$\mprset{fraction={===}}
  \inferrule {a = b \in A} {b = a \in A}$$

\end{document}
```

Here is what it produces.

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Can you show us what you've tried? A minimal example starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` would make your question clearer and easier to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say whether this is suitable for your use. (A minimal working example - or a non-working example showing what you've tried - would help clarify this.) But certainly **ebproof** allows doubled inference rules:

[image: double trouble]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{ebproof,geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{prooftree}[rule style=double]
  \Hypo{ a = b \in A}
  \Infer1{ a = b \in B}
\end{prooftree}
\end{document}
```